# Is there a way to import data into neo4j without using csv?

Tags: neo4j

I want to import data into `Neo4j`. My dataset has about 6 billion rows of data, and I am trying to avoid exporting and importing through `CSV`. Since this would take a while, is there an alternative way?

Comment: You can programmatically migrate the data using the binary [Bolt channel](http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/)?

Comment: Where is your data currently?

Comment: My data is in our current RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fluent in Java, you can also use the parallel batch importer APIs directly from Java, see:

- https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-rdbms-import
- https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-dataset-import